# Set params to Shopware Navigation Path

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, shopware, shopware6

The first page I call up in my Shopware 6 plugin should have a standard ID over the Vue Router.

```
routes: {
        list: {
            path: 'list/:id',
            component: 'plugin-list'
        },
    },

    navigation: [{
        id: 'plugin-list',
        label: 'Plugin',
        path: 'plugin.index.list/1',
        icon: 'default-shopping-paper-bag-product',
        parent: 'sw-catalogue',
        position: 100
    }]
```

The error that is passed by Vue Router is this:
[vue-router] Route with name 'plugin.index.list/1' does not exist

and the Component gets the wrong route. The route itself works without the parameters.

Thanks

I've already tried to pass the route as an array in the navigation, like 'path: 'plugin.index.list/{id: 1}', or to specify that as a separate parameter in the navigation.

```
    navigation: [{
        id: 'plugin-list',
        label: 'Plugin',
        path: 'plugin.index.list',
        params: 'id: 1'
        icon: 'default-shopping-paper-bag-product',
        parent: 'sw-catalogue',
        position: 100
    }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params` should be an object.

```js
navigation: [{
    id: 'plugin-list',
    label: 'Plugin',
    path: 'plugin.index.list',
    params: {
        id: '1'
    },
    icon: 'default-shopping-paper-bag-product',
    parent: 'sw-catalogue',
    position: 100
}]
```

Comment: Shame on me, that make sense. Thank you for your help again <3